# Jquery sum on input boxes

Tags: jquery

I am using following html form code...

```
<li><input type="text" class="paytax" name="payment[tax][]" /> <input type="text" class="payship" name="payment[shiping][]" /> <input type="text" class="paytotal" name="payment[total][]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" class="paytax" name="payment[tax][]" /> <input type="text" class="payship" name="payment[shiping][]" /> <input type="text" class="paytotal" name="payment[total][]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" class="paytax" name="payment[tax][]" /> <input type="text" class="payship" name="payment[shiping][]" /> <input type="text" class="paytotal" name="payment[total][]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" class="paytax" name="payment[tax][]" /> <input type="text" class="payship" name="payment[shiping][]" /> <input type="text" class="paytotal" name="payment[total][]" /></li>
```

I am trying to get total of .paytax and .paytax ($('.paytax').val()+$('.payship').val();) but its adding total of first li input to each .paytotal, please help me with proper code.

thanks for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption (without seeing any javascript code) is that you're trying to show the total in each line item.  Tax + Shipping = Total. This code accomplishes that.

```
$(".paytax,.payship").live("keyup", function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest("li");
    var tax = parseFloat($li.find(".paytax").val());
    var ship = parseFloat($li.find(".payship").val());
    if(isNaN(tax)) tax = 0;
    if(isNaN(ship)) ship = 0;
    $li.find(".paytotal").val(tax + ship);
});
```

Comment: its not working, i think you have forgot to add .keyup or change function on input boxes.

Comment: _He_ didn't forget anything.  _You_ forgot to actually say that that's what you wanted.  Please be more clear in the future if you expect answers to be accurate to your requirements.

Comment: I think *you* forgot to mention that you wanted it on keyup!

Comment: thats right, i am sorry if i couldn't provide proper information, what i want to do is, i am appending these fields using jquery and user can create upto 10 fields and each <li> total should be different according to passed value of .paytax and .payship

Comment: My answer should work fine for you. If you're going to ask people for help, **PLEASE** take the time to write a proper question with all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 0;
$('input.paytax, input.payship').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

This will total all the inputs of either of those classes.

UPDATE:

I see now what you're trying to do.  You want line-by-line totals... Missed that.  Go with the other posted answer (Jesse Gavin's).  Mine will total the entire thing.

Comment: would it total .paytax and .payship?

Comment: Wouldn't _what_ be ".paytax" and ".payship"?  Oh, you want to tally both?  See update.

Comment: are we still missing keyup or change function on inputs?

Comment: Your question made no mention of either of those things.  See my comment on Jessegavin's post.